# What are good strategies to test for gaps in automated data migrations between releases?

Tags: automated-testing

Given the following example MongoDB document in a collection *person*, which goes through different processing steps:

```
{
  'status': 'Step 2 is finished'    
  'name': 'Some Name'
  'affiliation': 'Gang of Four'
}
```

**Old software release:**
Documents were created in process step 1 without the field *affiliation*.
The missing field was added later in process step 2.

After step 1:

```
{
  'status': 'Step 1 is finished'
  'name': 'Some Name'
}
```

After step 2:

```
{
  'status': 'Step 2 is finished'
  'name': 'Some Name'
  'affiliation': 'Gang of Four'
}
```

**New software release:**
The entire document is created in step 1. Step 2 relies on the existence of the field *affiliation* and fails if it is not present.

**The gap:**
A diff of the document schema between old and new release does not indicate a change, so no migration is built. When the new release is deployed, there are documents in the database which were produced by the *old* processing step 1, and are thus missing the *affiliation* field. Step 2 fails on these documents.
The existing automated tests create test data dynamically though API calls, and so it is not possible to run them on 'old' data.

**My ideas so far:**

- Generic tests, which search for documents in 'Step 1 finished' status and run the 'step 2 code' on them. Given a larger number of possible status and transitions, the number of necessary test scenarios would soon grow.
- Base existing automated tests on static, raw database test data, which is versioned with the releases. This adds the burden of manual test data management which I would like to avoid.

**What are good strategies to find these kind of gaps with automated tests, or to avoid them in advance?**

Answer (score 1):

> What are good strategies to find these kind of gaps with automated tests ...

You could do a compare on the JSON string from one system to the other or do a SQL `EXCEPT` statement on the tables if you have access to those. This will tell you what is in one table but not the other.

> ... or to avoid them in advance?

[Software versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) is used to indicate if you are looking at the "old" release or the "new" one. [API versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning) allows you to explicitly test the "old" one or the "new" one. You should always know which you are testing when you are testing it.